# plot projects - Plot plugin is not initialised successfully in app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using plotprojects plugin for location based notifications in app: http://www.plotprojects.com/.
The app is build on ionic cordova framework.
I am calling plot.init() inside $ionicPlatform.ready() function. 
However the plot.isEnabled () function gives output as Plot is disabled sometimes after launching the app. It happens randomly. Should I call plot.isEnabled() method later in the code to get correct status of plot?

```
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      //org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    //window.localStorage.setItem("IsLaunched","YES");
    var plot = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/plot");
        plot.init();
        console.log('after plot init');
    plot.isEnabled(function(enabled) {
    var plotEnabledState = enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled";
    console.log("Plot is " + plotEnabledState);
}, function (err) {
    console.log("Failed to determine whether Plot is enabled: " + err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It takes some time before Plot is initialized. Plot initializes in the background. When calling `plot.isEnabled()` straight after calling `plot.init()` then it will return `false`. If you wait a second before calling `plot.isEnabled()` then it will return `true`.